# Can we make change in Seccubus tool to support Retina Scanner

Tags: security

I want to add Support for Retina scanner in Seccubus tool, will it easy? Actually i want to automate the things which Nessus does in Seccubus tool. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is quite easy. You need to convert the output to simple XML format named IVIL and make a script to run and import scans.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the other scanners as a guide to help write a collector for Retina, if anyone is still doing this. do-scan calls seccubus/scanners/[scan name]/scan which then runs the actual scanner with arguments and all. Then the report is saved in /tmp/seccubus.$$ ($$ is the process ID) then it is used as an input file to the command seccubus/bin/[something2ivil] and an output file of /tmp/seccubus.$$.ivil.xml is created which is the input to seccubus/bin/load_ivil and /seccubus/bin/attach_file.

If Retina by default outputs an XML report, then you can take a lot from say the Zap scanner and change things as needed to suit Retina. You would need the files seccubus/scanners/Retina/defaults.txt description.txt help.html and scan to have Retina a viable option on the web interface and a seccubus/bin/retina2ivil script that would convert the XML report to the IVIL format.

If Retina does output an XML report, then a lot of the work is already done for you with all the Zap files. But, to get retina2ivil done correctly you will have to experiment with correctly parsing the XML structure of Retina's outputs. Using the statement 
    "print Dumper([xml data field/fields]);"
should help you determine if you are correctly parsing the XML or if you're assuming the structure incorrectly.